# Why doesn't SMS spam go to the Unknown Senders tab on iPhone Messages?

Tags: iphone, messages, sms, spam

On iPhone Messages, SMS text messages come through from political groups and all kinds of other nonsense.  These are not phone numbers I interact with.  Some of them are short codes?

Why don't they all go to the "Unknown Senders" tab, since I have that setting turned on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Apple documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201229):

> You can filter iMessages from people who aren't saved in your
> Contacts.

There is difference between iMessages and SMS/MMS. You can read about it in Apple documentation: [About iMessage and SMS/MMS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207006)

Based on that it is relatively safe to assume that if you have SMS (text in green bubbles) then filtering doesn't apply.